# What does agility affect in Fallout New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I've read a lot of conflicting information about what the agility SPECIAL stat does in the game. The factors it affects I've read, of which some are almost certainly false are the following:

- Total number of APs (Action points)
- Regeneration rate of APs
- Reloading speed
- Running speed
- Accuracy with weapons
- Weapon spread

Is there any reliable data, maybe even quantitative, on what the effects of the agility stat really are? I could only find a lot of guesses, no hard data.

Comment: Doesn't it say in game when you mouse over stats? Or is that incorrect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The list is mostly accurate, if somewhat misleading. Agility grants 3 AP per point, affects, draw speed and reloading speed of weapons, and increases your **Guns** skill, which affects their Accuracy and Spread.

Comment: Do you know how much it affects movement speed per point? And gun skill?

Comment: Gun skill is 2 points / point, and is reflected in the Pip Boy. Movement speed, I haven't quantified, but it is absolutely noticeable. If you're playing on the PC, just use the Console and set your Agi to 1 and then to 10.

Comment: The reloading one is very unfortunate, as I used agility as a dump stat in my new build.

Comment: I've just tried it with the console and I see a huge effect of agility on reloading speed, but no effect on movement speed at all.

Comment: Hmm... that's odd. Perhaps it reduces the penalty relative to Armor or Sneak? I'll play around and do some testing when I get home tonight.

Comment: @Fabian the console?

Answer (score 2):

Does not affect run speed at all.

I tried making a char with 1 agility and one with 10 agility.

They both used exactly 48 seconds on the distance I tested.

It does affect reload speed A LOT. But not melee speed.

If you don't use guns dump it to 1. If you use guns but not vats have it at 5-6. If VATS player increase higher as wanted.

Answer (score 1):

**Agility affects your reload speed**.

Before the Sierra Madre DLC, there was a bug that allowed the player to glitch their Agility past 10.

By exploiting this bug, I found that reloading took around 30 milliseconds but noticed no other major differences.